# Unexpected token for Sequelize DataTypes.STRING

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm new to creating a database with Sequelize and Postgres and ran into an error trying to define a model. When running the server, I hit an error of "Unexpected token ." with DataTypes.String.

Using the following versions on node 8.4

"sequelize": "^3.30.4",

"sequelize-cli": "^3.0.0"

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    email: {
      DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    password: {
      DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    latlng: {
      DataTypes.STRING
    }
  });

  return User;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the types in declaration of User model. Need to declare "type"

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    latlng: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    }
  });

  return User
};
```